# Tailwind plugin for adding custom utility not applying on Next

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm pretty new to tailwindcss and I am wondering why my custom utility is not applied.

```
// tailwindcss.config.js
const plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin");

module.exports = {
  purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      borderColor: ["group-focus"],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addUtilities }) {
      const newUtilities = {
        "break-word": {
          wordBreak: "break-word", // actually break-all exists but not break-word
        },
      };
      addUtilities(newUtilities);
    }),
  ],
};
```

and I followed these steps from the [tailwind official doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs)

```
# If you're on Next.js v10
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest

# If you're on Next.js v9 or older
npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

my next version being 10.1.2
[next version screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sleAA.png)

resulting in this

```
//package.json
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@feathersjs/client": "^4.5.11",
    "next": "10.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.4.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Is there anything I missed ?

Answer (score 3):

Styles should follow CSS-in-JS syntax (see [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#css-in-js-syntax)).

Just add a period `.` character before the class name.

```
const newUtilities = {
  ".break-word": {
    wordBreak: "break-word",
  },
};
```

Comment: That's it ! thank you very much @Nikolai Kiselev